# Cant install WinUSB

Tags: 16.04, winusb

I'm trying to create a windows USB stick on the Ubuntu new release here is what I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

and the results where:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package winusb
```

I've tried installing it using the Saucy package with the code

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/freshlight/+files/winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_amd64.deb
```

it gave me these results

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/freshlight/+files/winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_amd64.deb
--2016-06-19 16:30:47--  https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/freshlight/+files/winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_amd64.deb
Resolving launchpad.net (launchpad.net)... 91.189.89.223, 91.189.89.222
Connecting to launchpad.net (launchpad.net)|91.189.89.223|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/ubuntu/freshlight/+files/winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_amd64.deb [following]
--2016-06-19 16:30:47--  https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/ubuntu/freshlight/+files/winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_amd64.deb
Reusing existing connection to launchpad.net:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://launchpadlibrarian.net/158567123/winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_amd64.deb [following]
--2016-06-19 16:30:47--  https://launchpadlibrarian.net/158567123/winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_amd64.deb
Resolving launchpadlibrarian.net (launchpadlibrarian.net)... 91.189.89.229, 91.189.89.228
Connecting to launchpadlibrarian.net (launchpadlibrarian.net)|91.189.89.229|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 177698 (174K) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: 'winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_amd64.deb.2'

winusb_1.0.11+saucy 100%[===================>] 173,53K   606KB/s    in 0,3s    

2016-06-19 16:30:48 (606 KB/s) - 'winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_amd64.deb.2' saved [177698/177698]
```

then I've tried installing this file

```
sudo dpkg -i winusb_1.0.11+saucy1*
```

and it gave me these results

```
dpkg-split: error: error reading winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_amd64: Is a directory
dpkg:../../src/unpack.c:123:deb_reassemble: internal error: unexpected exit status 2 from dpkg-split
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 17):

What you are trying to do will not work ... you try to install an Ubuntu **Saucy** package on **Xenial**. Instead you can use the built-in `gnome-disk-utility` to create the Windows installation media.

Open `Disks` and select Restore Disk Image from the menu on the top right of the application.
Choose the Windows installation file and the USB drive to write it to, then click Start Restoring.

Comment: I tested this, and the usb disk was not recognized as a bootable device in bios. I would follow this guide to make WinUSB work in Ubuntu 16.04: http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/make-bootable-windows-10-usb-install.html

Comment: @miceagol just click `Additional partition options` -> `Edit partition` -> mark as `Bootable`

Comment: @Viktor What if the `Edit partition` button is grayed out?

Answer (score 4):

Winusb doesn't work in 16.04 (xenial) because there is no ppa for xenial (yet). You can find newer winusb versions here: http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/pool/main/w/winusb/ , but I doubt any of them will work in xenial.

Answer (score 4):

You can get it to work following this guide. [Install WinUSB on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://onetransistor.blogspot.com/2016/04/install-winusb-on-ubuntu-1604-lts.html)