# Release file does not exist

Tags: update-manager

[image: When I am running command update-manager, this warning appear]

When I run `update-manager` command on terminal, I get this error"

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file. N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

The `404 error` suggests there are no package candidates on that repository for ubuntu xenial. That is because the ppa does not exist for xenial (16.04), as you can see [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/dists/). The latest packages available corresponds to 15.04 (vivid). It seems that the PPA for WinUSB is no longer being maintained by its author. Follow [these](http://onetransistor.blogspot.com/2016/04/install-winusb-on-ubuntu-1604-lts.html) instructions to install WinUSB on 16.04. Also, check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/788977/308164) for an alternative method to WinUSB.

For workaround, you can simply removing the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt update
```